# How to add a box in this ListView for uploading image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I have to create a quiz engine application. I am using a ListView for inserting the questions under specific quiz.

I have the following database design:

```
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
Question Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
QuestionImage: ID, QuestionID, URL
```

What I want now is making the admin being able to embedd an image to any one of these questions. How can I do that since I have two different tables in the database. One for the questions and one for the images as shown in the design above.

I know I should not post too much code or information, but I have to do it to make it clear:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataKeyNames="QuestionID" InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

            <EditItemTemplate>

                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="UpdateButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/update24.png" ToolTip="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/cancel324.png" ToolTip="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionIDLabel1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                    </td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </EditItemTemplate>

            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>

            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="InsertButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/add24.png" ToolTip="Add" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="CancelButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/clear24.png" ToolTip="Cancel"  runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                    <%--<td>
                        &nbsp;</td>--%>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionOrderTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("QuestionOrder") %>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="AnswerExplanationTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </InsertItemTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="SelectButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/select.png" ToolTip="Select" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                            <%--<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />--%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div ><table id="thetable" width="97%" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; border:2px solid #003366; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="background-color:#C6D7B5;">
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">...</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Question Order</th>
                                <th style="border-bottom:2px solid #003366; ">Answer Explanation</th>
                            </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody><tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr></tbody>
                    </table></div>     
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <tr style="">
                    <td>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="DeleteButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/delete24.png" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />

                        <asp:ImageButton ID="EditButton" ImageUrl="Images/icons/edit24.png" ToolTip="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="QuestionOrderLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("QuestionOrder") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="AnswerExplanationLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("AnswerExplanation") %>' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:QuizSysDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Question].* FROM [Question] INNER JOIN [QuizContent] ON [QuizContent].[QuizID] = @QuizID"

            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Question] WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID" 
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Question] ([Question], [QuestionOrder], [AnswerExplanation]) VALUES (@Question, @QuestionOrder, @AnswerExplanation)" 


            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Question] SET [Question] = @Question, [QuestionOrder] = @QuestionOrder, [AnswerExplanation] = @AnswerExplanation WHERE [QuestionID] = @QuestionID">

                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionID" Type="Int32" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="Question" Type="String" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="QuestionOrder" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AnswerExplanation" Type="String" />
                </UpdateParameters>

            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ListView1" Name="QuizID" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**So how to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `<asp:FileUpload>` control.. For help regarding control, check this site.

[asp.net-tutorials](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/)

Comment: I know but where it fits inside the ListView?

Comment: Mate, Just Insert FileUpload control into the ItemTemplate of your ListView. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add :

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="PictureIDUploader" runat="server" />
```

and in your page behind code  add this

```
 protected void ListView2_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {

            case "Insert":
string Imagepath = "~/UploadedImages/";
                FileUpload fu2 = (FileUpload)ListView2.InsertItem.FindControl("PictureIDUploader");
                if (fu2.HasFile)
                {
                    string exten = Path.GetExtension(Server.MapPath(fu2.FileName));
                    string Filename2 = DateTime.Now.ToOADate().ToString() + exten;
                    Session["TheImage"] = Filename2;
                    string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Filename2).ToString();
                    string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Imagepath)) + Session["TheImage"].ToString();
                    fu2.SaveAs(filepath);
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["TheImage"] = "NoImage.png";
                }
                //Hiding the insert template
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorLabel.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

now all what you need is to add this to your datasource :

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="TheImage" Type="String" SessionField="TheImage" />
```

you don't need another table for images "QuestionImage" you only need to a new column "TheImage" on your "Question" table and modify your insert query to :

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Question] ([Question], [QuestionOrder], [AnswerExplanation],TheImage) VALUES (@Question, @QuestionOrder, @AnswerExplanation,@TheImage)"
```

that is it :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. And what about the Queries in the SqlDataSource?

Comment: Some questions don't have images. Besides that, I may use one image for two or three questions. So I think it will be good if I have it in another table.